# run psql after installation

Tags: postgresql, passwords

I just installed PostgreSQL on my computer. In some stage of the installation I was requested to define a password (but was not requested to set user). The installation completed successfully. Now I changed directory to `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin` and write in command line

```
psql
```

I got a request for password for user `xxx` that I use to login to Windows. I tried to enter the password I had defined, but no symbol is shown and the cursor doesn't move. After "Enter" I get message

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "xxx"
```

So I think that something wrong but I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: You are trying to start the server. Use your windows authentification password. The one that you set up at install is for user postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login as database user `postgres` rather than using the default (the user of the same name as the operating system user):

```
psql -U postgres
```